# TypeORM property is nullable but receive "Cannot return null for non-nullable field x.x"

Tags: typescript, graphql, typeorm, typegraphql

I have a data model with all fields nullable given that the dataset isn't consistent right now, but I still want to work with the data.

This is a fragment of the model:

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class SomeEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({
        type: 'bigint',
    })
    @Field()
    id: number;

    @Column({
        nullable: true,
        type: 'text'
    })
    @Field()
    var1: string


    @Column({
        nullable: true,
        type: 'text'
    })
    @Field()
    var2: string
}
```

But upon doing a graphQL query, I get the following error:

```
 "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field SomeEntity.var1",
```

The field is null as I can check it on the database, but given that I have set nullable to true I would not be expecting this error.

anyone have a clue? Thanks guys.

Comment: Hint: What does the TypeORM decorator have to do with the GraphQL type for the field?

Comment: Thank you friend!

Comment: Can you provide the piece of code on the generated schema?

Comment: You need to pass `{ nullable: true }` to the `@Field()` decorator too.